# Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.when trying to have the value as a int

Tags: angular

I'm getting this error when trying to make an assignment, I need the result to be a whole value. what am I doing wrong?

```
pesoTotalEntregable:number=0;
.
.
.
this.pesoTotalEntregable=parseInt(this.pesoTotalEntregable-parseFloat(data[0].peso_total));
```

Comment: What type is `data[0].peso_total`?

Comment: The argument of `parseInt` should be a string but, in the present case, it is a number. Use `Math.round`, `Math.floor` or `Math.ceil` instead of `parseInt`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `data[0].peso_total` can be parsed as a valid number, you can simply do this

```
pesoTotalEntregable: number = 0;
.
.
this.pesoTotalEntregable = parseInt(this.pesoTotalEntregable - Number(data[0].peso_total));
```

Comment: What are the data types of all of the properties?